# How to detect change in query string without using react-router in react application and also how do we get access to search params?

Tags: reactjs, astrojs

I have a select element and I want to filter the list of items when the select filter changes.
Along with this I am want to add the selected option in the url query string. I am not using react-router dom. I using astro for this project.
The prblem I am facing is that , when I use the following snippet

```js
  const url = new URL(window.location.href);
    url.searchParams.set("team", e.target.value.toLowerCase());
    window.location = url;
```

the entire page gets reloaded. Is there anything else I can do?

For my second question, we have got `window.location.search` Cna we directly access the query string with the keys?
Eg: `/?team=abc` I want to directly access team instead of doing regex or string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me -  `history.pushState(null, "", url.toString());`